# How to embed Google Assistant in web application?

Tags: jsf, web-applications, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible to include the google assistant into my local web application so that everyone can use it? I've got a JSF-Application that runs on a local tomcat 7 server. My goal is to change the views by voice. I want to do it with the [google assistant sdk](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview#features).

There is the service sdk (python, all functions) and the library sdk(gPRC (java), general function). I tried the [java-client](https://github.com/mautini/google-assistant-java-demo), but the hotword detection only works for the service sdk. I need the hotword detection.

Can I run the service python google assistant and my jsf-app on one tomcat server? I can't get my head around it and need your help.

This is only the first step to my goal. Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hotword detection would be non-trivial to implement. A web application contains two parts: a *client*, which would be the web browser, and the *server*, which is your local tomcat server.

Web apps basically work with multiple clients communicating to one server through HTTP requests, primarily through Javascript. Your server then processes this, and the cool thing is that the server can be any language you want.

However, the client cannot directly interact with server-side code. This means that locally running feature like hotword detection on the server cannot be directly controlled by the client. You'd need to use a client-side hotword detection library, which would presumably need to be written in Javascript.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. You really helped me out. It is too complicated for me to make it possible. My JSF-Application will be delivered with a Chrome Browser. I hope the google assistant will be integrated soon, [here more detail](https://voicebot.ai/2018/11/07/google-assistant-on-its-way-to-chrome/).